# Is there an equivalent to node_modules directory in python pip

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pip, node-modules

I sometimes use single local `pip` installs like:

```
pip install Flask==0.12.2 --ignore-installed --target=.
```

Is there an equivalent to `npm`'s directory `node_modules` in python pip?